# WordPress VisualComposer Assets Missing

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

My WordPress site became very slow and investigation reveals that there are several CSS files missing from my file structure relating to the Visual Composer icon picker.

From ..\wp-content\plugins\visualcomposer\visualcomposer\Helpers\AssetsShared.php:

```html
            'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/iconpicker.bundle.css' => [
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/batch.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/dripicons.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/entypo.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/feather.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/fontawesome.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/linearicons.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/lineicons.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/material.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/metrize.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/mfglabs.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/monosocial.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/openiconic.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/socials.bundle.css',
                'sharedLibraries/iconpicker/dist/typicons.bundle.css',
            ]
```

All these icon bundles are missing from sharedLibraries. I've tried resetting Visual Composer and re-downloading the elements, but it doesn't replace these files. Does anyone know where I can get them? And/Or why they might have disappeared?

Comment: No-one knows where these are or where they come from?